# angularfire2@5.0.0-rc.10 .snapshotChanges() not able to let you get the doc.payload.doc.data()

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

#### Version info

**Angular:** 6.0.4

**Firebase:** 5.0.3

**AngularFire:** 5.0.0-rc.10

```
ng-test-angular6@0.0.0 /home/amine/docker-projects/ng-test-angular6
├── @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.6.8
├── @angular/animations@6.0.4
├── @angular/cli@6.0.8
├── @angular/common@6.0.4
├── @angular/compiler@6.0.4
├── @angular/compiler-cli@6.0.4
├── @angular/core@6.0.4
├── @angular/forms@6.0.4
├── @angular/http@6.0.4
├── @angular/language-service@6.0.4
├── @angular/platform-browser@6.0.4
├── @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@6.0.4
├── @angular/router@6.0.4
├── @types/jasmine@2.8.8
├── @types/jasminewd2@2.0.3
├── @types/node@8.9.5
├── angularfire2@5.0.0-rc.10
├── codelyzer@4.2.1
├── core-js@2.5.7
├── firebase@5.0.3
├── jasmine-core@2.99.1
├── jasmine-spec-reporter@4.2.1
├── karma@2.0.2
├── karma-chrome-launcher@2.2.0
├── karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter@2.0.1
├── karma-jasmine@1.1.2
├── karma-jasmine-html-reporter@0.2.2
├── protractor@5.3.2
├── rxjs@6.2.0
├── ts-node@5.0.1
├── tslint@5.9.1
├── typescript@2.7.2
└── zone.js@0.8.26
```

#### How to reproduce these conditions

Have a look on [the angular project ng-angular6-angularfire5.0.0-rc.10](https://github.com/mappedinn/ng-angular6-angularfire5.0.0-rc.10)

Just clone, install and serve.

#### Debug output

The issue is coming from the function in that line [L20](https://github.com/mappedinn/ng-angular6-angularfire5.0.0-rc.10/blob/master/src/app/data.service.ts#L20)

```
  fetchAvailableExercices() {
    this.db.collection('availablesExercices')
    .snapshotChanges()
    .pipe(map( docArray => {
      return docArray.map( doc => {
        console.log(doc);
        return(
           {
           id: doc.payload.doc.id,
           name: doc.payload.doc.data().name,
           duration: doc.payload.doc.data().duration,
           calories: doc.payload.doc.data().calories,
         }
        //doc
      );
      });
    }))
    .subscribe(exercices => {
      this.availableExercices = exercices;
      this.availableExercicesChanged.next([...this.availableExercices]);
    });
  }
```

The errors I am getting are:

```
Property 'name' does not exist on type '{}'.
Property 'duration' does not exist on type '{}'.
Property 'calories' does not exist on type '{}'.
```

In addition, I can not build a prod version of the angular application `ng build --prod`

But, if I take the document as it is (no setting to name, duration, calories), I am able the get the browser console the expected value is obtained:

```
> temp1.payload.doc.data()
{calories: 8, duration: 60, name: "Burpees"}


  fetchAvailableExercices() {
    this.db.collection('availablesExercices')
    .snapshotChanges()
    .pipe(map( docArray => {
      return docArray.map( doc => {
        console.log(doc);
        return(
        doc
      );
      });
    }))
    .subscribe(exercices => {
      this.availableExercices = exercices;
      this.availableExercicesChanged.next([...this.availableExercices]);
    });
  }
```

#### Expected behavior

- The following errors `Property 'name' does not exist on type '{}'.` has to desappear.
- Building a prod has to be successful

**PS:** AngularFire: 5.0.0-rc.8 **does not throw** the error message  `Property 'name' does not exist on type '{}'.`. Nevertheless, it fails to build a prod version of the angular application.

```
ng build --prod

Date: 2018-06-10T20:10:08.203Z
Hash: 3395c915a85b5198ef71
Time: 4427ms
chunk {0} runtime.a66f828dca56eeb90e02.js (runtime) 1.05 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {1} styles.d651e93934b267387a12.css (styles) 56.5 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {2} polyfills.cdf87a8e5b31fe8a11f1.js (polyfills) 130 bytes [initial] [rendered]
chunk {3} main.a2bc6cab25d0aa41c17a.js (main) 128 bytes [initial] [rendered]

ERROR in Error during template compile of 'AppModule'
  Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'AngularFireModule' was called.
```

Comment: Try reading the properties in this notation and see if that works `doc.payload.doc.data()['name']`

Comment: It worked perfectly. Thank you @TroyMyers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the new version of AngularFire, the code becomes:

```
  fetchAvailableExercices() {
    this.db.collection('availablesExercices')
    .snapshotChanges()
    .pipe(map( docArray => {
      return docArray.map( doc => {
        console.log(doc);
        return(
           {
           id: doc.payload.doc.id,
           name: doc.payload.doc.data()['name'],
           duration: doc.payload.doc.data()['duration'],
           calories: doc.payload.doc.data()['calories'],
         }
        //doc
      );
      });
    }))
    .subscribe(exercices => {
      this.availableExercices = exercices;
      this.availableExercicesChanged.next([...this.availableExercices]);
    });
  }
```

And building a prod application will straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

I had some issues with the versions of angularfire2 & firebase in your project.

This is what I did to get things working:

```
npm i angularfire2@5.0.0-rc.10 --save
npm i firebase@5.0.4 --save
```

In your `data.service.ts`: typed the `db.collection()` call

```
 fetchAvailableExercices() {
    this.db.collection<IExercice>('availablesExercices') //  <== This line
    .snapshotChanges()
    .pipe(map( docArray => {
      return docArray.map( doc => {
        console.log(doc);
        return(
          {
          id: doc.payload.doc.id,
          name: doc.payload.doc.data().name,
          duration: doc.payload.doc.data().duration,
          calories: doc.payload.doc.data().calories,
        }
      );
      });
    }))
    .subscribe(exercices => {
      this.availableExercices = exercices;
      this.availableExercicesChanged.next([...this.availableExercices]);
    });
  }
```

Two more remarks in your `app.module`:

- you should import AngularFirestoreModule (commented out)
- no need to provide for `AngularFireStore` here

Property errors are gone & build is working.
[Working example here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so003?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdata.service.ts)